# C# Ordering an Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I am looking to order an Array. You can compare 2 objects and they will give a return either -1 (which means the object should come before that one), 0 object is the same or 1 and the object should be behind that one in the array. I've looked up multiple ways to order an Array but could not find a solution for this one. I hope someone could help me out on this one. Thanks!

EDIT:
This is what I tried

```
    public virtual void Add(NAW item)
    {
        _nawArray[ItemCount()] = item; //igonore this
        for (int x = 0; x < _nawArray.Size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < _nawArray.Size; y++)
            {
                if(_nawArray[x].CompareTo(_nawArray[y]) == 1){
                    //x should go on the place of y
                } else if(_nawArray[x].CompareTo(_nawArray[y]) == -1){
                    //y should go on the place of x
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

ItemCount() gets the amount of used places in the Array.
But when ObjectX goes in the place of ObjectY I can not set ObjectX on the place of ObjectY (unless I copy it but that is not what I need). Anyone an idea?

Comment: So what have you tried? How does your code look like? Where exactly are your problems?

Comment: then try `Array.Sort` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @UnholySheep I am trying to sort my Array. You can compare 2 objects of the Array with a method. The result can be -1 means Object1 should be before Object2 in the array, 0 means it is the same, 1 means Object1 should be after Object2. I hope it is clear now :)

Comment: @JesseVlietveld simply repeating the same thing again does not make anything clear (and is not an answer to any of my 3 questions). My question was to see what you have tried and why it doesn't work. SO is not a free coding service, we are here to help you fix your problems.

Comment: Edited the post @UnholySheep

Comment: Your question is unclear and we ask you some questions but you don't respond anything useful. Make the effort to write good, clear questions.

Answer (score 3):

Well, just use `Array.Sort`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.110).aspx

something like this:

```
   MyType[] data = ...

   ...

   Array.Sort(data, (left, right) => YourFunction(left, right));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to sort your Array, you could take a look at this page, it may help you: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Array.Sort(yourArrayNameHere)
```

In case you mean anything else, please do share and be more precise in your question.

Comment: I meant to sort it but not alphabetical. You can compare 2 objects of the Array. The result can be -1 means Object1 should be before Object2 in the array, 0 means it is the same, 1 means Object1 should be after Object2. I hope it is clear now :)

Comment: @JesseVlietveld So if I understood you well, you have an array of Objects, which aren't strings as you said. Array.Sort method does that: _"Sorts the elements in an entire one-dimensional Array using the IComparable implementation of each element of the Array."_ I suggest you give it a try, in case I still didn't get it, please share a piece of your code to understand you more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Array.Sort (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Array.Sort(someArray)
```

But you need to implement interface IComparable in your class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Example:

```
class IntHolder : IComparable<IntHolder>
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(IntHolder  other)
    {
        return SomeInt.CompareTo(other.SomeInt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but you are comparing int right? I guess you misunderstood me. E.g. I have 10 objects in an Array and I want to order it I have to compare 2 objects and see which one should be infront of the other. That is the return I get from the method.

Comment: It's an example. The class might be very complex. In this case, you may code your own "CompareTo" logic.